# CreatePortalLink doesn't point to a dashboard but a payment url

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, next.js, stripe-payments

I have a project which uses the Stripe payments extension with Firebase. The app runs with Next JS.

Once the user is subscribed, I need a tab for them to manage their subscription. The extension tells you to run their cloud function, createPortalLink. Here is my implementation of it:
const functions = getFunctions(getApp())
const functionRef = httpsCallable(functions, "ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink")

```
    const {data} = await functionRef({
        returnUrl: window.location.href + "/plans",
        locale: "auto",
    })
    
    // @ts-ignore
    window.location.assign(data.url)
```

When I run this, it just goes to a payment page and not a dashboard which could allow you to manage, and most importantly, delete subscriptions.

Is there something I need to change or does it just work like this in test mode?

Comment: Where are you (or are you) specifying the customer ID?

Comment: Is there somewhere I should specify it?

Comment: Im not familiar with the firebase extension (which from your code appears to be a "wrapper") but you could refer to the stripe's official docs to get some ideas in addition. https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/sessions/object

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly the method `ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink` produced. Per [its Doc](https://github.com/invertase/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/master/codelab-steps/index.lab.md#access-the-stripe-customer-portal) it does look like to be a Customer Portal, but let's confirm to be sure.

You can take a look at your Stripe Dashboard's request log (https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs) to find out. A Customer Portal should be what you want, but in example, a Checkout Session will not.

Comment: I tried again today and the function worked unlike before. I just made sure to setup the customer portal in test mode.